# JAVA 8 doesn't have jrunscript, only jjs

Tags: java, elasticsearch, gradle

I've installed Java as `yum install -y java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel`

I'm trying to build a gradle project with an elasticsearch plugin `elasticsearch.esplugin` which is ultimately trying to run `jrunscript`, then failing when it can't find it.

My JAVA_HOME path appears to be set correctly to `/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk`. If I look at the path the build is trying to use for jrunscript, which is `/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk/bin/jrunscript`, I can see a number of files in that bin directory, including `jjs`, but not `jrunscript`

This is the error:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: 
Cannot run program "/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk/bin/jrunscript" 
(in directory "/usr/share/elasticsearch/ch_plugins/my-plugin"): 
error=2, No such file or directory
```

Why don't I have `jrunscript`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JAVA_HOME refers to JRE location. jrunscript tool is inside jdk\bin directory. Change JAVA_HOME to refer to jdk location. (it should be something like `/usr/lib/jvm/java-*-openjdk`)

Depending of how You run jrunscript, You might want to add jdk\bin directory to path. 
(if it is called like jrunscript instead of JAVA_HOME/bin/jrunscript )